# Hibernate Search: how to query fields in parent class?

Tags: jquery, hibernate, elasticsearch, querydsl, hibernate-search

I'm trying to make a query with Hibernate Search.
I would like to match a field that is in a Class extended from the parent (the child class is the @Indexed one).

Here is what i've done so far.

**-Price is the indexed class-**

```
@Indexed
@Table(name = "price_products")
public class PriceEntity extends AbstractPrice {

    .....
    .....
    .....

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private ECommerceProductEntity parent;
    

    public ProductEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(ProductEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    
}
```

**-Products is the parent class-**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "products")
public class ProductEntity extends AbstractProduct {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PriceEntity> prices;

    /.others fields../


    @Field(termVector = TermVector.YES)
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String tags;

    /.others getter and setters../
    

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<PriceEntity> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void setPrices(PriceEntity> prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    public void addPrice(ECommercePriceEntity price) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**-AbstractProduct is extended by the products-**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractProduct {
    /.others fields../
    @NotBlank
    @Field(termVector = TermVector.YES)
    private String description;
    /getter end setters/
}
```

**--Query--**

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager
        = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();

FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager2
        = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager2.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity(PriceEntity.class)
        .get();

Query myQuery = queryBuilder
        .bool()
        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().withConstantScore()
                .onField("products.description").boostedTo(9l).matching(query)
                .createQuery())
        .should(queryBuilder.phrase().withConstantScore()
                .onField("products.description").boostedTo(5l).sentence(query)
                .createQuery())

        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().withConstantScore()
                .onField("products.tags").boostedTo(3l).matching(query)
                .createQuery())
        .should(queryBuilder.phrase().withConstantScore()
                .onField("products.tags").boostedTo(1l).sentence(query)
                .createQuery())
        .createQuery();

org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery
        = fullTextEntityManager2.createFullTextQuery(myQuery, PriceEntity.class);
jpaQuery.setProjection("description");

List<PriceEntity> queryResults = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

With the code above i get the following error

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field products.description in ...
```

How to query by the fields "description" (in AbstractProduct) and tags in (ProductEntity) if the given entity to queryBuilder is PriceEntity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@IndexedEmbedded`.

```
@Indexed
@Table(name = "price_products")
public class PriceEntity extends AbstractPrice {

    .....

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    @IndexedEmbedded // <= ADD THIS
    private ECommerceProductEntity parent;
```

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "products")
public class ProductEntity extends AbstractProduct {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @ContainedIn // <= ADD THIS
    private List<PriceEntity> prices;
```

Then reindex all your data.

Then use the "parent." prefix when querying prices if you want to access product fields:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager
        = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();

FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager2
        = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager2.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity(PriceEntity.class)
        .get();

Query myQuery = queryBuilder
        .bool()
        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().withConstantScore()
                .onField("parent.description").boostedTo(9l).matching(query)
                .createQuery())
        .should(queryBuilder.phrase().withConstantScore()
                .onField("parent.description").boostedTo(5l).sentence(query)
                .createQuery())

        .should(queryBuilder.keyword().withConstantScore()
                .onField("parent.tags").boostedTo(3l).matching(query)
                .createQuery())
        .should(queryBuilder.phrase().withConstantScore()
                .onField("parent.tags").boostedTo(1l).sentence(query)
                .createQuery())
        .createQuery();

org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery
        = fullTextEntityManager2.createFullTextQuery(myQuery, PriceEntity.class);
jpaQuery.setProjection("parent.description");

List<PriceEntity> queryResults = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated).

Comment: I also added store= Store.YES in the field annotation of my AbstractProduct class